How to solve an evolutive-advection-diffusion problem with source term?
I am trying to solve a problem in relation with subglacial hydrology (https://gmd.copernicus.org/articles/8/1613/2015/gmd-8-1613-2015.pdf) which reads as follows:
equation 1
with equation 2
As you can see, there is an advection term, together with a diffusion term and in addition a source term. Do you know how to solve it correctly with FiPy?
I have tried the following code to solve it, but I think that the convection term is producing some issues, because the diffusion and source terms work well separately. ALso, I don't know if the way I have tried to implement the gradient in V, with functions previously defined (not shown below) is the correct way. As boundary conditions I am trying to impose W=0 at the edges of the domain.
Lx, Ly = 2500, 2500
Nx, Ny = 50, 50
dx, dy = Lx/Nx, Ly/Ny


Np = 20    
Nt = 500
dt=100


# Define the grid/mesh
mesh = Grid2D(nx=Nx, ny=Ny, dx=dx, dy=dy)
x, y = mesh.cellCenters[0], mesh.cellCenters[1]



# Define the model variable and set the boundary conditions
W = CellVariable(name="Water height", mesh=mesh, value=0.5)
b = CellVariable(name="Bedrock", mesh=mesh, value=numerix.array(bedrock(Nx,Ny,7)))
s = CellVariable(name="Surface", mesh=mesh, value=numerix.array(surface(Nx,Ny,1)))
H = CellVariable(name="Water height", mesh=mesh, value=numerix.array((s-b)))
P0 = CellVariable(name="Overburden pressure", mesh=mesh, value=numerix.array(rhoi*g*H))
P = CellVariable(name="Water pressure", mesh=mesh, value=numerix.array(calc_pressure(Nx,Ny,0,W,P0,'P0')))
hyd_pot=CellVariable(name="hydraulic potential", mesh=mesh, value=numerix.array(hydraulic_potential(P,b)))


X, Y = mesh.faceCenters

meshBnd = (mesh.facesLeft & (Y > 0)) | (mesh.facesTop & (X < Lx)) | (mesh.facesRight & (Y < Ly ) | (mesh.facesBottom & (X > 0)))

# Functions for bedrock, surface elevation, ice thickness, etc. For defining the gradient in the hydraulic potential.
bv=bedrock(Nx,Ny,7)
sv=surface(Nx,Ny,1)
Hv=np.maximum(sv-bv,0)
P0v=rhoi*g*Hv
Pv=calc_pressure(Nx,Ny,0,W,P0v,'P0')

phi=hydraulic_potential(Pv,bv)
phidx,phidy=grad_hyd_potential(phi,Nx,Ny,dx,dy)

# Solving the problem
eq = TransientTerm() == DiffusionTerm(coeff=rhow*g*k*W)\
     + ExponentialConvectionTerm(CellVariable(mesh=mesh,value=[k*phidx,k*phidy])) \
     + m/rhow

W.constrain(0., where=meshBnd)

# To save the solution in each time step and plot after that
my_sol = np.zeros((Np,Nx*Ny))      
my_sol[0,:] = W
k = 1

for step in np.arange(1,Nt):
    #print(step)
    eq.solve(var=W,dt=dt)
    if np.mod(step,Nt/Np)==0:
        my_sol[k,:] = W
        k += 1


The way you've defined the convection term is almost guaranteed to not work properly, but it's hard to say definitively, because all of the critical elements are missing. I recommend taking this to GitHub Discussions. StackOverflow is not well-suited to troubleshooting open-ended problems.
